# Why does the service broker require a master key after restoring to a different server?

Tags: encryption, service-broker

I've been moving some databases which use the service broker to new servers recently via backup and restore.  I've noticed that once I do this, these databases start throwing the database master key required messages in the log.  Encryption isn't being used in with the broker, and no keys are set in the original server and database, so why does it require one once I restore it? Is it maybe using the service master key if a database master key isn't set? My searching hasn't turned up specifics of what happens if you don't set one originally, it just seems to be assumed you have one set.  It's been mentioned that there are issues if it is not set, but we haven't had any.

Also, does it actually require a key? I'm starting to wonder if this is just an incorrect message, and if I just do the UID update with the alter statement, if that will resolve it, or do I have to set the key when moving to a new server?

Thank you!

Comment: can you post the message or error that you are receiving in error logs ?

Comment: It's this one: 
Service Broker needs to access the master key in the database 'MyDB'. Error code:26. The master key has to exist and the service master key encryption is required.

Answer (score 4):

When you restore a database, `TRUSTWORTHY` is automatically set to `OFF`.  For Service Broker, if you **don't** use encryption and **do** use cross-database message transmission, `TRUSTWORTHY` needs to be set to `ON`.

Try

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
```

...for all restored databases involved with Broker.

Comment: I will give this a try, but Trustworthy is off by default on databases, and on the source databases it is off. We aren't doing cross-database transmission as far as I know, we are using it with IIS only. I did look, and trustworthy hasn't been explicitly set on the originating databases either. If it does address the issue, the broker behaves differently on the originating server?

Comment: could be a server level setting too, perhaps...

Comment: Don't enable trustworthy on your service broker database by default. Turning on Trustworthy opens up some major security holes in SQL Server and can allow for privilege escalation.

Comment: @mrdenny good point, I should have put a disclaimer in there. I was operating under the assumption this was a cross-DB conversation.

Comment: @user42454 Can you share how you're starting dialogs? Are you specifying 'CURRENT DATABASE'? Is it possible there's a remote service binding or you're using a GUID that doesn't match the guid on the database? Did you set new broker on the db?

Comment: I found out some more info. We're using Query Notifications. It looks to me like the SQLNotificationRequest masks all the broker level details, so I'm not sure we know explicitly how the broker is used. My understanding of the Service Broker is that some of the parts are stored in master and msdb. That being the case, in addition to alter the UID, would we need to recreate the service, queues, and routes after restoring to a different server?

Comment: I'm not familiar with query notifications, only with custom service broker implementations. For THOSE, the objects are all database-level.

Answer (score 2):

Service Broker uses encryption by default unless you specify that you don't want to use it when sending the messages.  At some point the database master key had to be created unless like I said you were specifying that encryption was off when you send the messages (it might be when you create the conversation, I don't remember).

Anyway, when you restored the database if the key was only encrypted by the service master key on the last server then you wouldn't have been able to use it so you'd need to recreate it.

Comment: Yes, you specify no encryption when you BEGIN DIALOG.

Comment: I'll have to ask the devs to search he source and see how it's being done.

While I find that out, lets say I create a brand new database.  It won't have an encryption key. I can set Enable_Broker at this point without getting an error. If I then issue a begin dialog without specifying no encryption, what is it encrypted with? The service master key? I think this is the situation we are in.

If I go to the source databases there doesn't appear to be database master keys to transfer, which is part of the confusion of being asked for them later.

Comment: If you do a begin dialog without specifying that there's no encryption you should get an error back, or at least logged into the sys.transmission_queue DMV.

Comment: @mrdenny Can you please elaborate on your last phrase "so you'd need to recreate it."? I'm having the same problem. How do I recreate the service master key? Is it for database level or server level? Thank you.

Comment: You'll want to regenerate the master key as shown here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186937.aspx